# how to speed up kartograph.js?

Tags: javascript, raphael, kartograph

**Situation:**

There is a complex map in Kartograph.js with many svg paths.
For example this one :
http://kartograph.org/showcase/choropleth/

**Problem:**

init of the map is slow (up to 5 seconds)

On the other hand when complex map is rendered directly via Raphael.js like here:
http://raphaeljs.com/world/
the init is basically immediate.

**Question:**

Is there an easy way to speed up the first example?

**My thoughts:**

I was thinking that in Kartograph.js there is processing of raw svg and maybe even some resizing of paths, which is slow. Maybe it could be somehow precompiled into raphael calls, but I don't know where to even start.

I'd be very grateful for any hint.